# AVAudioEngine throws exception when connecting AVAudioPlayerNode to output

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avaudioengine

All I want to do (for now) is play a sound file using `AVAudioEngine` and `AVAudioPlayerNode`. Here's my code:

```
//Init engine and player
let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
let audioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()

//Hook them up
audioEngine.attach(audioPlayerNode)
audioEngine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: nil) // < error
```

While executing the last line, an exception is thrown. Nothing is printed to the console and the execution continues, but when I set an exceptional breakpoint I get the following with [LLDB](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/lldb-basics.html):

```
(lldb) po [$arg1 reason]
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xffffd593).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

What can't be accessed here? I haven't even loaded a file yet... Thanks for any hints.

*Environment*

- Xcode 8.2.1
- iPhone 5 running on iOS 10.3.2 (14F89)

**Edit**

Here is some more contextual information. The code above is part of an iOS game built with `SpriteKit` and `GameplayKit`. It is located in a subclass of `GKStateMachine`, within a method called `playSound`. This method is invoked in course of a touch event originating from my subclassed `SKScene` called `GameScene`. Upon `touchesBegan`, the call is delegated to all entities with a `TouchComponent` that have a method with the same signature (`touchesBegan`). These components will fire a `touchDown` event to their delegate, which is in turn my subclass of `GKStateMachine` called `GameStateMachine`. If the touch event is *correct* w.r.t. the game rules, the `score` property of my `GameStateMachine` is incremented. Within the `score` setter, the final method `playSound` is called if the score increases. Here's a sequence diagram of what I just described:

[image: Sequence Diagram showing how "playSound" is invoked]

Comment: How are you running this code? Is it a playground, part of an iOS app, is the code in a view controller? Could you give a bit more context? Because it seems that something gets deallocated before you try to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the exception thrown is **normal**. It occurs under any condition and in any environment I have tested, but does not interfere with normal functionality.

The reason why no sound was played is that the `AVAudioEngine` and `AVAudioPlayerNode` objects were released as soon as the function returned, because they had no strong pointers keeping them alive. I have fixed the issue by keeping those two objects as `properties`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a working example of playing a local file resource in a playground:

```
import AVFoundation
import PlaygroundSupport

// prevent program from exiting immediately
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "song", withExtension: "mp3")!
let file = try! AVAudioFile(forReading: fileURL)

let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
let audioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()

audioEngine.attach(audioPlayerNode)
audioEngine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: nil)

audioPlayerNode.scheduleFile(file, at: nil, completionHandler: nil)

// need to start the engine before we play
try! audioEngine.start()

audioPlayerNode.play()
```

This assumes that `song.mp3` exists in the playground resources directory.

Comment: Thanks for your code, I ran it in playground and it worked. Then I copied the exact code over to my project and the same error pops up at the same place. It doesn't work in iOS Simulator either. Please see my edited answer for further information.